# How to check if an el has a class that matches a value in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array and some `path` elements. I need to check if the `class` of a `path` matches one of the values in my array and if so add a class `fadeIn` to it, I tried this:

```js
var nationList = ["usa", "france", "italy"];
var foundNations = $.unique(nationList.sort());
$("path").each(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < foundNations.length; i++) {
    if ($(this).hasClass(foundNations[i])) {
      $(this).addClass("fadeIn");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.fadeIn {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<path class="spain">Spain</path>
<path class="italy">Italy</path>
<path class="germany">Germany</path>
<path class="usa">USA</path>
```

Comment: Your code is already working, as you can see from the snippet I edited in to the question. You've asked enough questions already to know how it works here; we need details on what isn't working.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i thought it wasn't working.. must be something else then which I am missing

Comment: Side note: You can replace all that code with: `var nationList = ["usa", "france", "italy"]; var foundNations = $.unique(nationList.sort());
$("path").filter("." + nationList.join(", .")).addClass("fadeIn");`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sure, yet I had no errors at all and the class wasn't added, so I'm here. I'm wondering, is it possible that I need to use pure js rather than jquery as it is on a leaflet svg path?

Comment: @rob.m - You mean "use the DOM directly" not "use pure js" (it's pure JavaScript either way). Sure you can: `querySelectorAll` and loop the results, modifying the classes via [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). (MDN says `SVGElement` inherits from `Element`, so presumably they have `classList`; if not, you have to append to `className` instead.) BTW, its' entirely possible your code wasn't working with real SVG elements, I seem to recall some jQuery issue with them. So perhaps delete this question and post one with a [mcve] as a runnable snippet..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok will do it now

Comment: @T.J.Crowder erhm.. posted a new question but I can't delete this one as there are answers..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718464/how-to-check-if-an-svg-path-has-a-class-that-matches-a-value-in-array-and-if-so

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I cannot close it myself as there are other answers

Answer (score 0):

You need to use document ready function rest of the things are already fine. You just missed document ready function. Here is the running code:

```
<style>
    .fadeIn {
        color: red;
    }
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
    var nationList = ["usa", "france", "italy"];
    var foundNations = $.unique(nationList.sort());
    $("path").each(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < foundNations.length; i++) {
        if ($(this).hasClass(foundNations[i])) {
          $(this).addClass("fadeIn");
        }
      }
    });
});
</script>

<path class="spain">Spain</path>
<path class="italy">Italy</path>
<path class="germany">Germany</path>
<path class="usa">USA</path>
```

Comment: had to make a new question with a working example, but it's not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718464/how-to-check-if-a-svg-path-has-a-class-that-matches-a-value-in-array-and-if-so-a#

Answer (score -1):

`.includes` function can check array value exist with provided value. If exist it return `true` ...So you can use that for your nationList array ..

```js
var nationList = ["usa", "france", "italy"];

$("path").each(function(){
   if(nationList.includes($(this).attr('class'))) {
    $(this).addClass('fadeIn');
   }
});
```

```css
.fadeIn {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<path class="spain">Spain</path>
<path class="italy">Italy</path>
<path class="germany">Germany</path>
<path class="usa">Usa</path>
```