# How to check if a svg path has a class that matches a value in array and if so add a new class

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, path, leaflet

I have an array and some `svg path` elements (I am using [leaflet map](https://leafletjs.com/)). I need to check if the class of a path matches one of the values in my array and if so add a class `fadeIn` to it.

```js
var foundNations = ["usa", "France", "Italy"];
document.querySelectorAll('path').forEach(path => {
  if (foundNations.includes(path.className)) {
   path.className.add('fadeIn');
    console.log(path.className);
  }
});
(function($) {
    var map = L.map('map').setView([45.4655171, 12.7700794], 2);
    map.fitWorld().zoomIn();
    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' + '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' + 'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
      id: 'mapbox.light'
    }).addTo(map);

    var mapHalfHeight = map.getSize().y / 2,
    container = map.zoomControl.getContainer(),
    containerHalfHeight = parseInt(container.offsetHeight / 2),
    containerTop = mapHalfHeight - containerHalfHeight + 'px';

    container.style.position = 'absolute';
    container.style.top = containerTop;
    map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
    var southWest = L.latLng(-89.98155760646617, -180),
    northEast = L.latLng(89.99346179538875, 180);
    var bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
    map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
    map.on('drag', function() {
      map.panInsideBounds(bounds, { animate: false });
    });

  // get color depending on population density value
    function getColor(d) {
      return d > 1000 ? '#800026' :
        d > 500  ? '#BD0026' :
        d > 200  ? '#E31A1C' :
        d > 100  ? '#FC4E2A' :
        d > 50   ? '#FD8D3C' :
        d > 20   ? '#FEB24C' :
        d > 10   ? '#FED976' :
              '#FFEDA0';
    }

    function style(feature) {
      return {
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        color: '#ffffff',
        dashArray: '',
        fillOpacity: 0,
        fillColor : '#FF0080',
        className: feature.properties.name
      };
    }

    var geojson;

    function selectNation(e) {

    }


   function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
      layer.on({
        click: selectNation
      });
    }

    geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
      style: style,
      onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(map);
})( jQuery );
```

```css
#map {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.fadeIn {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://www.jikupin.com/world.json"></script>

<div id='map'></div>
```

Comment: how is this question different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50717978/how-to-check-if-an-el-has-a-class-that-matches-a-value-in-array

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I was asked to delete the other one and reword it, check the last comments right below the other question

Comment: Please make the example **runnable** (as I [said before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50717978/how-to-check-if-an-el-has-a-class-that-matches-a-value-in-array#comment88444901_50717978)); [here's how](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha).

Comment: @rob.m - Best to actually delete that question. As of this comment, it's still there.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm trying to run the code as you suggested... but I can't delete the other question as there are answers and it doesn't let me ot.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder there we go, I've made an interactive example working on here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your bug is subtle. You are starting with an `Array` of `String`s:

```
var nationList = ["usa", "france", "italy"];
```

Then you're calling `String.prototype.includes`, passing `path.className` as an argument.

```
if (foundNations.includes(path.className)) { path.classList.add('fadeIn')
```

In there, you're implicitly **assuming** that `path.className` is a `String`. But, surprise surprise, it's not a `String`, it's a [`SVGAnimatedString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimatedString)!

```
console.log(path.className)
> [object SVGAnimatedString] {
   animVal: "germany",
   baseVal: "germany"
  }
```

Yes, class names for SVG elements can be modified during animations in some edge cases.

What you probably want to do is use the [`baseVal` property of the `SVGAnimatedString`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimatedString/baseVal):

```
console.log(typeof path.className.baseVal)
> "string"
```

And now everything should work more closely to the way you expect:

```
if (foundNations.includes(path.className.baseVal)) {
  path.classList.add('fadeIn')
}
console.log(path.className.baseVal);
> "spain fadeIn"
```

---

---

You have a second problem, due to another assumption. You're **assuming** that `path.className` contains just *one* class name, but [according to the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className), emphasis mine:

> `cName` is a string variable representing the class or **space-separated classes** of the current element.

In fact, if you use the developer tools available in your browser to inspect the SVG elements, you'll see things like...

> `<path class="Italy leaflet-interactive" stroke="#ffffff" ....></path>`

So in this case, you're assuming that the `className.baseVal` is going to be the string `"Italy"`, but in reality, it takes the value `"Italy leaflet-interactive"`.

The approach here is to use [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to iterate through the class name**s** to see if *any* of them match a given
group.

---

---

Furthermore, I think that this is an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I don't think you wanted to ask

> How to check if a SVG path has a class that maches `foo`?

but rather

> How to symbolize a SVG polygon in Leaflet when the feature matches `foo`?

Because I think that it is way more elegant to move the checks into the `style` callback function, like:

```
geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
  style: function(feature){ 
    var polygonClassName = feature.properties.name;
    if (nationList.contains(feature.properties.name)) {
        polygonClassName += ' fadeIn';
    }
    return {
      weight: 1,
      opacity: 1,
      color: '#ffffff',
      dashArray: '',
      fillOpacity: 0,
      fillColor : '#FF0080',
      className: polygonClassName
    };
  },
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

Leaflet offers convenient functionality like [`L.Path.setStyle`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#path-setstyle) that hides the complexity of dealing with selectors and SVG classes directly, as long as you keep references to your instances of `L.Polygon` around (which, in this case, you can do in the `onEachFeature` callback).

Comment: Thanks, I have added that bit on the question code and it isn't working  still

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot, makes sense