# How to check if clicked svg path has a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I run he following (using [leaflet map](https://leafletjs.com/)):

**HTML**

```
<svg>
  <path class="Mexico leaflet-interactive fadeIn"></path>
</svg>
```

**JS**

```
function selectNation(e) { 
  if(e.target.classList.contains("fadeIn")) {
    console.log("hello");
    var countryName = e.target.feature.properties.name;
    $("#myCountryName").attr("value", countryName);
    submitSearchForm();
  }
}

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  layer.on({
    click: selectNation
  });
}
```

But it gives me:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined

I tried:

```
if($(e.target).hasClass("fadeIn")) {...
```

But It does nothing and says nothing in console. I thought there was some issue with using `e.target` but this works: `var countryName = e.target.feature.properties.name;`.

I confirm `fadeIn` is there as a class on the `svg path`.

**UPDATE**

Adding more context:

I first run the map:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([45.4655171, 12.7700794], 2);
```

Once the map is loaded I ask for some variables to load via ajax callback, and these variables are set as path classes.

```
$.fn.almComplete = function(alm){
  var foundNations = $.unique(nationList.sort());
  $("path").each(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < foundNations.length; i++) {
      if ($(this).hasClass(foundNations[i])) {
        $(this).addClass("fadeIn");
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Once the class is added, each `path` now has `fadeIn` as a `class` and when I click on the `path` with that `class` I do:

```
function selectNation(e) { 
  if(e.target.classList.contains("fadeIn")) {
    console.log("hello");
    var countryName = e.target.feature.properties.name;
    $("#myCountryName").attr("value", countryName);
    submitSearchForm();
  }
}

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  layer.on({
    click: selectNation
  });
}
```

But I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined

And I do:

```
if($(e.target).hasClass("fadeIn")) {...
```

I get nothing.

**NOTE**

It has been pointed out that this question might be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718464/how-to-check-if-a-svg-path-has-a-class-that-matches-a-value-in-array-and-if-so-a) but on here I am simply checking if it has a class not trying to match anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840995/jquery-hasclass-method-fails-for-svg-elements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a svg path has a class that matches a value in array and if so add a new class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718464/how-to-check-if-a-svg-path-has-a-class-that-matches-a-value-in-array-and-if-so-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I researched slight more bit the event which was coming in your function was overridden dom event of the leaflet which does not allow the user to directly have the element which we did over the discussion.

As discussed in the chat classnames in leaflet events can be accessed as following `e.sourceTarget._path.className`. They have tried using oops here more information can be found at https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#class.

The below is the alternative code.

Sorry for delayed response. Here is the example.

```js
var svg = document.getElementById("ini")
var paper = Snap(svg);



var p = paper.path("M0,0L50,0L30,302").attr({
        fill: "#ff9900",
        stroke: "#bada55",
        strokeWidth: 5
    });
    console.log(p)
p.addClass("green");
var arr = ["green","red","blue"];
p.click(function(e){
  
  console.log(e.target.className, e.target.className.baseValue=="green");
  this.attr({stroke:getRandomColor()})
})
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
   var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
 }
 return color;
}
```

```css
.green{fill:green}
.blue{fill:blue}
.red{fill:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="ini">
 
</svg>
```

Comment: `function selectNation(e) { 
      console.log(e.target.className)` gives `undefined`

Comment: what is log of e.target

Comment: can we go to chat?

Comment: Sure I am slightly new please do let me know the link and please upvote if working.

Comment: i can't take you to chat since you're too new, I will upvote and accept if it'll work which isn't for now

Comment: anyway e.target in console gives all the propierties of the leaflet path, there is also the class objects but obviously wont' show fadeIn since fadeIn is added later on in the dom and it is not part of e.target

Comment: so if we do `if(e.target.className.baseValue == "fadeIn") {` it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseValue' of undefined`

Comment: can you post snippet of your code where you have used Snap and I think we can resolve this problem using animate method of snap

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172834/discussion-between-rob-m-and-ullas-hunka).

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

I removed the previous content as it doesn't apply, understood in chat.

Well, I see the code that works with the class is the one that actually adds it.

```
$("path").each(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < foundNations.length; i++) {
    if ($(this).hasClass(foundNations[i])) {
      $(this).addClass("fadeIn");
    }
  }
});
```

Then it can be used the same approach, so it can get a `this` object in the same way you use it. The approach is to compare the clicked node among the array of paths:

```
function selectNation(e) { 
  $("path").each(function() {
    if(e === this) { // or any sort of compare logic
      // this is the node
      if($(this).hasClass("fadeIn") { // ensure about the class
        console.log("hello");
        var countryName = this.feature.properties.name; // try 
        $("#myCountryName").attr("value", countryName);
        submitSearchForm();
      }
    }
  });  
}
```

To parse the path array each time any of them is clicked is not as efficient as direct access, but this way to walk dom arrays is used with libraries like [d3.js](/questions/tagged/d3.js) or [three.js](/questions/tagged/three.js) to apply animation frames and works great.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Ok thanks makes sense. I run the map, and after it has loaded, I do something else with loading some variables via ajax, when ajax has completed, I add the class fadeIn to each path. Then when the class is added, I click on the path. SO the timing shouldn't be the case on here

Comment: I have updated the question with more context to it, check if that helps

Comment: @rob.m check the updated solution. It uses the same way used to add the class.